# Custom Component in Endeca Studio - Nothing Displays in new portlet

Tags: oracle, tag-cloud, endeca, endeca-workbench

I followed Oracle Endeca Custom Visualization document and started with developing a custom portlet in eclipse.
When I deploy the same into the endeca-portal . Nothing displays in the component. But I see a lengthy code present in view.jsp . Can some one help me in displaying a Hello message in the portal.
And what is the one present in there already?

```
<div class="eid-simple-portlet">
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th><edisc:getMessage messageName="table-heading.data-set"/></th>
        <th><edisc:getMessage messageName="table-heading.record-count"/></th>
        <th><edisc:getMessage messageName="table-heading.attribute-count"/></th>
        <th><edisc:getMessage messageName="table-heading.sample-refinement"/></th>
        <th><edisc:getMessage messageName="table-heading.sample-keyword-search"/></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>     
    <c:forEach items="${viewModel.dataSetMap}" var="mapEntry" varStatus="dsLoop">
        <c:set var="dataSetKey" value="${mapEntry.key}" />
        <c:set var="dataSetInfo" value="${mapEntry.value}" />

        <%-- set up search action URL --%>
        <portlet:actionURL var="searchURL" name="${filterActionName}">
          <portlet:param name="${dataSetKeyParam}" value="${dataSetKey}"/>
          <portlet:param name="${searchKeyParam}" value="${dataSetInfo.sampleSearchKey.key}"/>
          <portlet:param name="${searchTermParam}" value="${sampleSearchTerm}"/>
        </portlet:actionURL>

        <%-- set up refinement action URL if the sample exists --%>
        <c:if test="${not empty dataSetInfo.sampleRefinement}">
            <portlet:actionURL var="refineURL" name="${filterActionName}">
              <portlet:param name="${dataSetKeyParam}" value="${dataSetKey}"/>
              <portlet:param name="${refinementNameParam}" value="${dataSetInfo.sampleRefinement.name}"/>
              <portlet:param name="${refinementSpecParam}" value="${dataSetInfo.sampleRefinement.spec}"/>
            </portlet:actionURL>
        </c:if>

        <tr <c:if test="${dsLoop.count%2==0}">class="even"</c:if>>
            <td>${dataSetInfo.displayName}</td>
            <td><fmt:formatNumber type="number" value="${dataSetInfo.recordCount}"/></td>
            <td><fmt:formatNumber type="number" value="${dataSetInfo.attrCount}"/></td>
            <td>
                <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${not empty dataSetInfo.sampleRefinement and not empty refineURL}">
                    <a href="${refineURL}">
                        <edisc:getMessage messageName="refine-by-link-text">
                            <edisc:param value="${dataSetInfo.sampleRefinement.name}"/>
                            <edisc:param value="${dataSetInfo.sampleRefinement.label}"/>
                        </edisc:getMessage>
                    </a>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <edisc:getMessage messageName="refinement-sample-not-available"/>
                </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>     
            </td>
            <td>
                <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${not empty dataSetInfo.sampleSearchKey}">
                <a href="${searchURL}">
                    <edisc:getMessage messageName="search-for-link-text">
                        <edisc:param value="${dataSetInfo.sampleSearchKey.displayName}"/>
                        <edisc:param value="${sampleSearchTerm}"/>
                    </edisc:getMessage>
                </a>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <edisc:getMessage messageName="search-sample-not-available"/>
                </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you have your sample code available? What are the steps you are performing to deploy it?

Comment: Thanks @radimpe . I figured out. There was major.minor exception which was happening. After correcting out it worked.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Endeca custom poertlet.]

This is the sample output I got after using the sample code. This is developed using liferay framework. So learning liferay framework to develop these custom components will help. It was erring out earlier because of some major.minor exception. Selecting the appropriate jdk version to compile solved the issue.